# Bellman-Ford algorithm correct & standard implementation

Tags: java, graph-theory, bellman-ford

I have been trying to understand the correct implementation of Bellman-Ford by following these resources: [1](http://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs161/cs161.1176/Slides/Lecture12-lowquality.pdf) & [2](https://leetcode.com/problems/cheapest-flights-within-k-stops/discuss/163698/easy-java-Bellman-Ford)

If we already know that the given weighted digraph doesn't contain a cycle (hence no negative cycle either), is following a correct implementation of Bellman-Ford algorithm?

```
int src = 0;
        int V = nodes.length; // 0 to n-1 nodes
        int E = edges.length;

        double[] distTo = new double[V];
        for (int i = 0; i < V; i++) {
            distTo[i] = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        }
        int[] edgeTo = new int[V];

        distTo[src] = 0.0;

        for (int i = 1; i < V - 1; i++) {

            double[] distToLocal = new double[V];
            for (int j = 0; j < V; j++) {
                distToLocal[j] = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < E; j++) {

                int to = edges[i].to;
                int from = edges[i].from;
                int weight = edges[i].weight;

                if (distToLocal[to] > distTo[to] && distToLocal[to] > distTo[from] + weight) {
                    distToLocal[to] = distTo[from] + weight;
                    edgeTo[to] = from;
                }
              distToLocal[to] = Math.min(distToLocal[to],distTo[to]);

            }
            distTo = distToLocal;
        }
```

The first issue that I am having with above implementation is that, if there are only 2 nodes in the graph with a directed edge from source node to destination node, then the first `for` loop needs to be modified to start with `0` instead of `1` as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < V - 1; i++) {
```

If I make the above change, is it still a correct implementation?

**Variation in implementation**

If there is no need to find the shortest distance of a node from `src` with maximum of K edges where K is [0,V-1], then following variation also seem to give correct result.

```
int src = 0;
        int V = nodes.length; // 0 to n-1 nodes
        int E = edges.length;

        double[] distTo = new double[V];
        for (int i = 0; i < V; i++) {
            distTo[i] = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        }
        int[] edgeTo = new int[V];

        distTo[src] = 0.0;

        for (int i = 1; i < V - 1; i++) {

            /*double[] distToLocal = new double[V];
            for (int j = 0; j < V; j++) {
                distToLocal[j] = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
            }*/

            for (int j = 0; j < E; j++) {

                int to = edges[i].to;
                int from = edges[i].from;
                int weight = edges[i].weight;

                if (distTo[to] > distTo[from] + weight) {
                    distTo[to] = distTo[from] + weight;
                    edgeTo[to] = from;
                }
            }
            //distTo = distToLocal;
        }
```

I think I understand why the variation works, however I am curious why resource [1](http://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs161/cs161.1176/Slides/Lecture12-lowquality.pdf)  doesn't mention this.

Are there any downsides to implementing this variation? Clearly, the variation has better memory requirement.

Note: I know that I can use topological sort SPT algorithm when there are no cycles in the weighted digraph, but I am trying to understand the correctness of Bellman-Ford.

Answer (score 0):

Bellman-Ford algorithm states that after V-1 phases of relaxation of every edge would calculate the minimum distance between source to any destination. In your implementation, you run V-2 iterations of each phase. Actually, two of implementations are the same, you can just reuse the old array of distances.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question! Are there any circumstances when the first implementation is preferred over second? I know for sure that `max K edges' restriction is a scenario that requires the first implementation. Are there any other scenarios?